# How to start a specific mode with emacs?

Tags: emacs, major-mode

Users use 'M-x auto-revert-mode' for starting auto revert mode. How can I set the .emacs file to do the same thing when emacs starts?

How to start a specific mode, when a major mode starts? For example, how to set the .emacs file when I want to start the auto revert mode when LaTeX mode starts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want auto-revert-mode on for all files, add:

```
(global-auto-revert-mode 1)
```

If you want it for files for specific modes, try:

```
(add-hook 'latex-mode-hook '(lambda () (auto-revert-mode 1)))
```

and substitute the mode name for `latex`.